# Dynamic text in static table view not displayed correctly until tableview dequeues reusable cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, text, dynamic

I have a static table view that has three sections and various numbers of rows per section. The dynamic text displays correctly within the first section, however, the dynamic text in the third section does not appear correctly until the tableview dequeues a reusable cell. When the tableview first loads the dynamic text is displayed correctly in section 1 with the cell height large enough to display all text. The other cell has the dynamic text at the correct size but the cell height is wrong, it only shows the first line of text. When I move the cell off the screen and back again it shows the dynamic text with cell height correct. As it is a static tableview I'm not using the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I have connected ibOutlets to the tableviewcontroller and then I set the dynamic text as follows

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0 {

       myLabel.text = "This is the dynamic text to display"

        myLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)

        myLabel.accessibilityLabel = myLabel.text


    }

      if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1 {

        myOtherLabel.text = "I also want this dynamic text to display"

        myOtherLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)

        myOtherLabel.accessibilityLabel = myOtherLabel.text

    }


}
```

Is there a way to force all the cells to dequeue in my viewdidload method? Is there a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: How is it not displaying correctly? Is this really the code or has it been modified?

Comment: That's the code. When the tableview first loads the dynamic text is displayed correctly in section 1 with the cell height large enough to display all text. The other cell has the dynamic text at the correct size but the cell height is wrong, it only shows the first line of text. When I move the cell off the screen and back again it shows the dynamic text with cell height correct. willDisplayCell must initially get called with the initially displayed cells, then when I move the second cell off the screen then back on it must get called again. I need to work out how to call it for all cells

Comment: I see what you mean Beyowulf. I do have other cells displayed, my code looks like I just have a couple of cells. I thought I would simplify it to get my point across.

Comment: How are your constraints setup?

Comment: I just set them up in the storyboard. Once the second cell goes off screen and back on it displays perfect. Normally with dynamic cells we can use cellForRowAtIndexPath but there must be a way to apply the above code to cells that are currently displayed and cells that are not displayed simultaneously.

Comment: Yes there is. It is `tableView.reloadData()` you're saying that doesn't work. I'm trying to explore other issues, but you're being difficult.

Comment: I use tableView.reloadData() in both my viewDidLoad() and viewDidAppear() but no success. It's very frustrating.

Comment: Right my point is even if you could place reloadData in some magic spot to get it to work correctly, that would still be a work around. You shouldn't have to call reloadData immediately after loading the data.

Comment: True, I was thinking about creating a function and calling it in viewDidLoad() and viewDidAppear(). A function that would affect every static cell and not just the cells that are in the current view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for tableView.reloadData().  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData

Comment: Kyle I use that in viewDidLoad and also viewDidAppear but no luck :(

Comment: It is already called once on viewDidLoad.  You might need to call it after you make the modifications to the underlying data.